# call Zend framework view helper from within own view helper

Tags: zend-framework

Zend Framework 1.12

I have written my own view helper and need to call a Zend view helper from within it.

In my view file, I can call

```
$this->formSelect (...) to get a select dropdown
```

however in my own view helper file

```
$this->view->formSelect (...)
```

causes an error

```
Call to undefined method Zend_View_Helper_MilestoneList::formSelect()
```

How can I access Zend Framework view helpers from within there?

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to call another View Helper.

Your view helper extends must be extend Zend_View_Helper_Abstract, so that it has access to the $view. Then you may simply call helpers as you would from a view, i.e.

```
$this->view->generalFunctions()->progressMeter();
```

For example you can access it in to your view:

```
<?php

class Zend_View_Helper_FormVars extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {

    /* ... */

    public function mkCategoryCodeSelectGroup($codeTypeArr=array(),
        $codesArr=array()) {
        $html='';
        $html. $this->view->generalFunctions()->progressMeter();
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Please set class name as per your need. and just try it.

let me know if i can help you

Comment: I can't get $this->view->formSelect()->formSelect(...) to work either.

Answer (score 0):

I found that

```
$selectFormHelper = $this->view->getHelper('FormSelect');
$selectFormHelper->formSelect(...)
```

works, but

```
$this->view->formSelect(...)
```

does not.

I'm not sure why that is, but happy to live with it for now.